# Add JS in HTML which is inserted into JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I use [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) gem in my app for translate js. Script add option to selecte. I try translate text in this option, but my code not workc.

```
$("#advert_category_id").prepend("<option value=''>"I18n.t('js.forms.selecte.choose-category')"</option>");
```

How add JS in HTML which is inserted into JS? Xzibit help me!

**Solution**

```
$("#advert_category_id").prepend("<option value=''>"+I18n.t('js.forms.selecte.choose-category')+"</option>");
```

Thanks [@mike-c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371184/mike-c)

Comment: Are you getting any errors when compiling or in your console?

Comment: Rails say: "SyntaxError: [stdin]:63:63: unexpected identifier". That all. Problem in js syntax.

Comment: You need to concatenate your strings together. Put a plus before `I18n.t('...` and after that same function call. For future reference, you should include the error in your original question.

Comment: Thank you. this is what I need!

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered ?